# how to apply Windows function in HiveQL in spark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, hivecontext

I have seen posts discussing the [usage of windows function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32769328/how-to-use-window-functions-in-pyspark-using-dataframes). But i have some questions.

1. Since it is can only be used in HiveContext. How can i switch between SparkSQLContext and HiveContext given i am already using SparkSQLContext?
2. How is that possible to run a HiveQL using windows function here? I tried

   ```
   df.registerTempTable("data")
   from pyspark.sql import functions as F
   from pyspark.sql import Window
   ```

   ```
   %%hive
   SELECT col1, col2, F.rank() OVER (Window.partitionBy("col1").orderBy("col3") 
   FROM data
   ```

and native Hive SQL

```
SELECT col1, col2, RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY col1 ORDER BY col3) FROM data
```

but neither of them works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can i switch between SparkSQLContext and HiveContext given i am already using SparkSQLContext?

You cannot. Spark data frames and tables are bound to a specific context. If you want to use `HiveContext` then use it all the way. You drag all the dependencies anyway.

> How is that possible to run a HiveQL using windows function here

```
sqlContext = ...  # HiveContext 
sqlContext.sql(query)
```

The first query you use is simply invalid. The second one should work if you use correct context and configuration.

Comment: Thanks! I am using HDInsight Spark and their kernel will launch HiveContext and SparkContext. So i thought i could run the Windows function over there. Also, is that possible to run HiveQL on top of a spark dataframe?

Comment: Not exactly. You can register table and use `sqlContext.sql` but Spark is not fully compatible with HiveQL. Usually it shouldn't matter though.

Comment: Thanks! but is there anyway to actually run similar windows function in sqlcontext as well?

Comment: No, as for now there isn't