# Spark support for using Windows function

Tags: python, hadoop, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am using spark version 1.6.0..while I am using spark with python.I found that windows function are not been supported by the version of the spark that I am using,as when I tried to use windows function in my query(using sparksql) it gave me an error as 'you need to build spark with hive functionality'.Following that I searched various things and found that I need to use spark version 1.4.0.,which I did with no luck.Some posts also suggested to build spark with hive  functionality.But I did not found the right way to do it.
when used spark 1.4.0.I got the following error.

```
raise ValueError("invalid mode %r (only r, w, b allowed)")
ValueError: invalid mode %r (only r, w, b allowed)
16/04/04 14:17:17 WARN PythonRDD: Incomplete task interrupted: Attempting to kil
l Python Worker
16/04/04 14:17:17 INFO HadoopRDD: Input split: file:/C:/Users/test
esktop/spark-1.4.0-bin-hadoop2.4/test:910178+910178
16/04/04 14:17:17 INFO Executor: Executor killed task 1.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 2)
16/04/04 14:17:17 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 1.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 2, localh
ost): TaskKilled (killed intentionally)
16/04/04 14:17:17 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Removed TaskSet 1.0, whose tasks have
all completed, from pool
```

Comment: Can you post stacktrace of the error you are getting ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that this is the third time that I answer a similar question :

- [Using windowing functions in Spark](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36172311/3415409).
- [Window function is not working on Pyspark sqlcontext](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36011943/3415409).

Windows function are supported with HiveContext and not regular SQLContext.

Concerning how to build spark with hive support, the answer is in the official [Building Spark documentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/building-spark.html#building-with-hive-and-jdbc-support) :

Building with Hive and JDBC Support
To enable Hive integration for Spark SQL along with its JDBC server and CLI, add the -Phive and Phive-thriftserver profiles to your existing build options. By default Spark will build with Hive 0.13.1 bindings.

#### Apache Hadoop 2.4.X with Hive 13 support (example):

```
mvn -Pyarn -Phadoop-2.4 -Dhadoop.version=2.4.0 -Phive -Phive-thriftserver -DskipTests clean package
```

#### Building for Scala 2.11

To produce a Spark package compiled with Scala 2.11, use the -Dscala-2.11 property:

```
./dev/change-scala-version.sh 2.11
mvn -Pyarn -Phadoop-2.4 -Dscala-2.11 -DskipTests clean package
```

There is magic here, everything is in the documentation.

Comment: Just added 'install' after 'clean' in the above building script : mvn -Pyarn -Phadoop-2.4 -Dhadoop.version=2.4.0 -Phive -Phive-thriftserver -DskipTests clean install package  and the spark was builded in one and half hour.

Comment: The package is long to build, but the install option isn't going to install spark. It's going to copy the create jar into your .m2 repository.