# Spark with HiveContext - AnalysisException: Could not resolve window function 'first_value'

Tags: java, apache-spark, dataframe, hive

What is wrong with this usage of `first`? I want to take the first row for each `id` in my dataframe, however it returns an error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Could not resolve window function 'first_value'. Note that, using window functions currently requires a HiveContext;
```

The code is:

```
WindowSpec window = Window.partitionBy(df.col("id"));
df= df.select(first(df.col("*")).over(window));
```

I am using a `HiveContext`.

Comment: Can you - for tests - try following code: `WindowSpec window = Window.partitionBy(df.col("id"));
df= df.select(first(df.col("id")).over(window));`
It's possible that window function cannot be used with *

Answer (score -1):

Did you read/create your spark dataframe with SparkContext or HiveContext?
Window functions require HiveContext to be used

More detail here:
[Window function is not working on Pyspark sqlcontext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36011843/window-function-is-not-working-on-pyspark-sqlcontext/36011943#36011943)

Comment: Author wrote, that he is using HiveContext